# Combine repeated property constraints in one Symfony custom validator

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I have an application which has differtent entities with a password property. At the moment each entity has a repeated group of property constraints for the password property:

```php
<?php
public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
     // ...
     $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('password', new Length(...);
     $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('password', new NotBlank(...);
     $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('password', new Custom1(...);
     $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('password', new Custom2(...);
     // ...
}
```

I would like to have a custom validator "PasswordValidator" which "groups" all the different constraints as mentioned above. In that case, I only need to add one property constraint to each password property.

Like this:

```php
<?php
public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
     // ...
     $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('password', new MyCustomPassword(...);
     // ...
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `All` Symfony2 built-in constraint: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html

Basically, that's how it should look in your case:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
     // ...
     $metadata->addPropertyConstraint(
        'password', 
        new Assert\All(
            new Assert\Length(...),
            new Assert\NotBlank(...),
            new Assert\Custom1(...),
            new Assert\Custom2(...)
        )
     );
```

Comment: I want to seperate these 4 constraints from the entity, this is is just another way of coding my snippet.

Comment: Well, then you could implement your own constraint that would be very similar to the given All constraint except that its members will be hardcoded. I personally think that it wouldn't make your code more readable, but the opposite.